# Android Java : How to completely remove instance of ScheduledExecutorService when App is not in foreground

Tags: java, android, scheduledexecutorservice

I have the following code block that loops to check last seen, I'd like to stop it from running, and free resources once app is no longer in foreground.

With the following, the runnable doesn't stop, it just continues.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> dfgh;

   private void getLastSeen() {
      AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            dfgh = scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  if (!Presence.screenLocked(A) && Presence.inForeground(A)) {
                     MessageHelper.getLastSeen(RECIPIENT, A);
                     System.out.println("Checking Presence");
                  } else {
                     System.out.println("App not in foreground or screen is locked");
                     dfgh.cancel(true);
 //cancel here doesn't seem to cancel.
                  }
               }
            }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         }
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the scope of `ScheduledExecutorService` is local to `run` then you will not be able to control it from other methods.

If you see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html you will see that they have their instance as a field.  On this field you can call [shutdownNow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow())